# Apache Camel SEDA queue with LIFO-ordering?

Tags: apache-camel

I need a camel component that does pretty much what the SEDA component does (i.e. a queue), but I need the messages in last-in-first-out order. As far as I can see in the documentation, there is no configuration option for the SEDA component that would allow that.
Is there another way to configure that, or another component that would be suitable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer by Claus Ibsen set me on the right path, but was a bit vague, so I'll present the final solution I came up with in a bit more detail. It's in kotlin and Spring-Boot:

First off, it seems like a PriorityBlockingQueue is the only available implementation where you have controll over the delivery order, all other standard implementations seem to be FIFO only.

The PriorityBlockingQueue takes a comparator as a constructor parameter, so I wrote a short comparator to sort exchanges by creation time:

```
/**
 * Comparator to sort Exchanges in ascending order by time, newest first.
 * Is inconsistent with equals()!
 */
class NewestExchangeFirstComparator : Comparator<Exchange> {

    override fun compare(o1: Exchange, o2: Exchange): Int =
            when {
                o1.created.after(o2.created) -> -1
                o1.created.before(o2.created) -> 1
                else -> 0
            }
}
```

Something that surprised me about the PriorityBlockingQueue is that it sorts ascendingly, not descendingly. In other words, the smallest value gets delivered first, not the highest as I'm used to from priority queues I worked priorly with in other languages.

Next, I made a Bean to instantiate the queue:

```
@Configuration
class QueueConfig {
    @Bean("FiloBlockingQueue")
    fun createQueue(): PriorityBlockingQueue<Exchange> =
            PriorityBlockingQueue<Exchange>(10, NewestExchangeFirstComparator())
}
```

First I tried with a BlockingQueueFactory as suggested by Claus Ibsen, but for some reason Camel didn't seem to use it. Although I used the queueFactory parameter and it recognised the type of my QueueFactory, the create method was never called. So I made a bean that instantiates the queue and passed that to the queue parameter of the route, and that worked:

```
from("$SEDA_IMAGE_QUEUE?queue=#FiloBlockingQueue")
        .routeId("upload to gateway")
        .log("Found new image \${header.filename}")
        .process().message {
            gatewayFacade.uploadImage(it.body as ByteArray, it.getHeader("filename") as String)
        }
```

And that's that.

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe configure a custom `BlockingQueueFactory` with the `defaultQueueFactory` option on the `SedaComponent`. In that queue factory you can create a queue that uses a different ordering.